# Update/Refresh display when using Listbox in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I am new to XAML and C#. I have a simple display with a listbox which is populated via elements in an ArrayList. When I add an item to the list, I would like the listbox to be updated so that it also displays the new value.

How would I go about doing this?
I saw that some people have used:

```
 listBox.InvalidateArrange();
 listBox.UpdateLayout();
```

But I cannot get this to work for me.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Don't use an ArrayList (for anything, but especially not for this), use an `ObservableCollection`. When you add items to the ObservableCollection, the ListBox will add them automatically with no further work on your part. If you'll want to modify the properties of the items in the collection and have the UI update, the items in the collection will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Yep. Take a look at: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32164.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-2.aspx

Comment: Thank you @EdPlunkett and Andy for your suggestions. Switching to an Observable collection solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions in the comments from Ed Plunkett and Andy, I was able to solve my issue by switching from an `ArrayList` to an `ObservableCollection`.

So every time a new entry was added, the `ListBox` updated immediately.